# Ejecutar update (oracle) completando sentencia desde Dataframe

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente Dataframe (df)

```
id   b   c

1    a   x1

2    a   xx1

3    b   x1

4    d   xxxx1
```

Lo que quiero hacer desde mi `script` de `python` es un `update` a una base de datos `Oracle` y que este se complete y ejecute leyendo de mi df, es decir algo así

```
dupdate=pd.read_sql("update tabla set campo=df['c'] where id = df['id'] and b=df['b']",engine)
```

Gracias 
Un saludo

Comment: ¿Has probado [`df.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Answer (score 0):

debes hacer un loop ya que es un arreglo:

```
for i in range(0,len(df['c'])):
  dupdate=pd.read_sql("update tabla set campo={0} where id = {1} and b={2}".format(df['c'][i],df['id'][i],df['b'][i]),engine)
  # lo que sigue en tu codigo
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.
No reconoce df['c']

    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'c'